# Why is it that no classical surface, except the sphere, is a suspension over any space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

In the book 'Homotopical Topology', exercise 4, chapter 2 asks:

> Prove that no closed (that is, without holes) classical surface except $S^2$ is homeomorphic to a suspension over any other space.

It looks like, we have to show any genus g surface (for g > 0) cannot be written as a suspension of some space. All we know at this point in the book is the definition of a suspension. No invariants (fundamental groups, homology groups, ...) have been introduced yet.

I don't know how to approach this question. A hint will be very helpful.

Comment: Normally closed means compact and without boundary. Hint for the problem: compute $\pi_1$.

Comment: If $T$ is a topological space, then small neighborhoods of each endpoint of the suspension of $T$ are homeomorphic to a cone over $T$. Since surfaces are manifolds, small neighborhoods of points are homeomorphic to disks. So if a surface is a suspension, it must be the suspension over a circle.

Comment: @Tyrone this question appears before $\pi_1$ is introduced

Comment: @NoelLundström the question says fundamental groups and homology groups have not been introduced yet

Comment: @Neal this assumes that the only think that disks are cones over are circles (which is not true). Disks can also be considered as cones over $[0,1]$ so it could be a suspension over an interval, which yields a disk again. I don't personally know if there are other spaces over which disks are cones. Although I suppose these would be the only spaces to consider since we want a cone over a 1-dimensional compact manifold, of which these are the only two.

Comment: Maybe you should include a definition of what a 'classical surface' is. We have no idea what tools are supposed to be available.

Comment: @Tyrone: Classical surfaces are not defined but the polygonal representation of surfaces has been discussed.

Comment: I highly doubt there is any proof you can reasonably be expected to come up with at this stage of the book.  Probably you can make a geometric argument along the lines that Neal is suggesting but the details are very nontrivial--for instance, it is far from obvious that the cone on $T$ actually must be homeomorphic to a disk (a priori, the cones over $T$ could be weird sets inside of disks that form a different neighborhood base).